# Why concatenate ls = foldr (++) "" ls works?

Tags: haskell

```
concatenate :: [String] -> String
concatenate ls = foldr (++) "" ls
```

if we follow this pattern:

```
foldr (+) 0 [1..1000000] -->
1 + (foldr (+) 0 [2..1000000]) -->
1 + (2 + (foldr (+) 0 [3..1000000])) -->
```

(from [https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl'](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl%27))

we should have

```
foldr (++) "" [1..1000000] --->
1 ++ (foldr (++) "" [2..100000]) ---> 
1 ++ (2 ++ (foldr (++) "" [3..100000])) --->
```

I've seen that ++ is for joining lists together. But `1` is not a list. How it can be `++` with other thing?

Comment: The `concatenate` function you gave, by itself, is very different from your last example. One important difference: Your last example does not type check. Do you know the definition of `String`?

Comment: `concatenate [1..1000000]` doesn't work either, because, just as you remarked, `[1..1000000]` is not a list of strings.

Comment: @DavidYoung It's not *quite* the case that it doesn't type check. If someone were to provide Num and Enum instances for `[a]` (or, with FlexibleInstances, `[Char]`), the expression would be valid. With enough tomfoolery, you could obtain `foldr (++) "" [1..10] == "12345678910"`. So on its own it's more of a constraint failure than a type error. Of course, still certainly not the expression anybody actually intends to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foldr (++) "" [1]
=
1 ++ ""
```

does *not* work. It causes an error, because `1` is not a `String`.

```
foldr (++) "" ["1"]
=
"1" ++ ""
```

does work, because `["1"] :: [String]`, i.e. `"1"` is a `String`.

Your function is declared as `concatenate :: [String] -> String` thus in `foldr (++) "" ls`, `ls :: [String]` just like `["1"] :: [String]`. So it works, because the types fit.